# how to execute special test case with soapui groovy script?

Tags: groovy, soapui

how to execute special test case with soapui groovy script?

testRunner.runTestCaseByName('ExitGame');

Answer (score 2):

The more compact one would be - for above question, To execute any particular the step add another line

```
def tc = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.testSuites["TestSuite1"].testCases["TestCase3"]

def ts1 = testRunner.gotoStepByName("loginRequest1")
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a [page here](http://www.eviware.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=7587) that might help?

Code copied here (and updated with your suite name) for posterity

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.support.MockTestSuiteRunner;
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.support.MockTestSuiteRunContext;

project = testRunner.getTestCase().testSuite.getProject()
testSuite = project.getTestSuiteByName( "ExitGame" )

mockRunner = new MockTestSuiteRunner( testSuite )
mockContext = new MockTestSuiteRunContext( mockRunner )
testSuite.runTearDownScript( mockContext, mockRunner )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this as well -

```
def project = context.testCase.testSuite.project
def TestSuite = project.getTestSuiteByName("TestSuite_Name")
def testCase1 = TestSuite.getTestCaseByName("ExitGame") // Put your testCase Name here
def testStep1 = testCase1.getTestStepByName("REST Step 1") // Put your testStep Name

// Run testStep only
testStep1.run(testRunner, context)

// Run testCase [here it is "ExitGame"]
def properties = new com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap()
testCase1.run(properties, false)
```

Or You can run the testCase by following script as well

```
testCase1.run(null, true) // You don't need to have `properties` in this case.
```

**Caution: The above script should be in different testCase/testStep. If it is in same testCase, it will in infinite loop**